# different wallpaper for each workspace ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, workspaces, desktop-background

so how to select different wallpaper for each workspace in Ubuntu 14.04?

I've tried to install unity-tweak but didn't found anything about having different background image for each workspace...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to do this install the following

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

1. Open the Compiz Setting Manager
2. Under Image Loading click JPEG and SVG to turn them on
   [image]
3. Under Utility click Wallpaper on
   [image]
4. Click the icon for Wallpaper to enter it
5. In the dialog click New
6. In the dialog browse to the location of the background image.
7. Repeat this step for each background
   [image]

Comment: couldn't be more clear :p

Comment: Do I have to reboot or something? it doesn't work.

Comment: Works great except all my desktop icons disappear

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I might have never noticed that because I don't like Desktop icons. There are apps that might do this now without this trick